# asp.net session store hastable

Tags: asp.net

I have a web forms application. When the user logs in I would like to retreive settings from the database that relates to that user.

So that I don't need to make a database call in the application when the settings are needed, I'm thinking about using the session object to store the values. Is this a good solution?

And if: Should I use for example a hastable or just store each value in the session.

```
Session["SomeSetting"] = true;
Session["smtp"] = "Somesmtp.ee.no";
```

or

```
Hastable settings New Hastable();
settings.Add("SomeSetting",true);
settings.Add("smtp","Some...");
```

There will be something like maximum 30 settings..

Comment: You might want to look at the [ASP.NET Profile Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class that holds the data and put that class in a Session object.
Something like this:

```
public class MyInfo{
    private String name {get;set};
    private String smtp {get;set};

    public MyInfo(){}

    public void fill(){}//fill from DB
}
```

Once the users come to your page you set up a new MyInfo object for that user and put it into a Session like this:

```
MyInfo myinfo = new MyInfo();
myinfo.fill();
Session["user_info"] = myinfo;
```

Comment: Ok, but will there be a problem with the size? And the performance when putting a object with that much information in the Session, or maybe it's not that much info?

Comment: When I have done this I have hade much much larger classes with subclasses without any performance issues. If you are only to have 30 or so objects then you shouldn't even be close to performence problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save user-specific settings or state then you can use `Session` but these settings for an application level then I suggest you to use `<appSettings>` in `web.config.`

Comment: I use App settings already for Application settings. Thank you